# How to change each font?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, math-fonts

I'm writing my thesis and I'd like to do these things:

1. Using [Garamond](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cormorantgaramond) font for Serif, [Cabin](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cabin) for Sans, [Latin Modern](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lm) for Math, and [Inconsolata](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata) for monospaced. How to set each one?
2. Garamond has to be the main font.
3. Cabin is for titles of chapters, sections, etc. How to set Bold for the chapters, semi-bold for sections, and so on?

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Garamond}\setsansfont{Cabin}\setmonofont{Inconsolata}` use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: For the third point: Best approach depends on your class, so create an MWE we can tinker with. If you're using a KOMA-class for instance, most of point 3 is already solved by the class's defaults (except for the different weights).

Comment: I don't like XeLaTeX takes too much compiling (in Overleaf), is there any option?

Comment: `\usepackage{lmodern}\usepackage{inconsolata}\usepackage{cabin}\usepackage{ebgaramond}` might work in pdfLaTeX (but I didn't check this setup). This page might help: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/